# How to change to pascal case in Mustache templates?

Tags: go, mustache

I have a mustache template like:

```
{{#attributes}}
func (event {{fileNameRoot}}) Get{{Name}}() string {
    return event.{{Name}}
}
{{/attributes}}
```

which outputs:

```
func (event JustATest) GetuserName() string {
    return event.userName
}
```

What I want is:

```
func (event JustATest) GetUserName() string {
    return event.UserName
}
```

How to achieve this? I am using Go and the mustache library [github.com/hoisie/mustache](https://github.com/hoisie/mustache).

The go code looks like:

```
data := map[string]interface{}{
    "fileNameRoot": "JustATest",
    "attributes":   schema.Attributes,
}

out, err := mustache.RenderFile("templates/test.go.mustache", data)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this useful library `github.com/iancoleman/strcase` to convert strings to different cases. In your case, you can convert `schema.Attributes` right before sending it as argument:

```
data := map[string]interface{}{
    "fileNameRoot": "JustATest",
    "attributes":   strcase.ToCamel(schema.Attributes),
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought about it earlier but couldn’t do it because at a few locations I want this Attribute values in camelCase and at other locations in PascalCase in the same template. 
Not entirely sure, but may be I can call some go method from template which can convert to whatever case I want. But that should be defined from Mustache template. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: then you can make a pull request to [github.com/hoisie/mustache] suggesting case converting methods.